# Django Model Extra Fields. Произвольное количество полей для модели или что то другое

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-model

Есть такое ТЗ. **Есть 2 модели: DataScheme, DataSchemeColumn**
Каждый DataScheme может содержать произвольное количесто колонок(DataSchemeColumn). DataSchemeColumn состоит из name и data type.

Нужно заимплеменить такие Data Types:

1. Full name (a combination of first name and last name)
2. Job
3. Email
4. Domain name
5. Phone number
6. Company name
7. Text (with specified range for a number of sentences)
8. Integer (with specified range)

**И САМОЕ ВАЖНОЕ И НЕПОНЯТНОЕ.** Некоторые data type могут поддерживать extra arguments(extra fields скорее), типо range для Integer. Каким образом изобразить data types и как их подружить с DataSchemeColumn ?

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ "в лоб" это хранить для нужных `DataType`-ов коллекцию параметров, для `Integer`, скажем, их будет два `min_value` и `max_value`.

Ну и ассоциацию между `DataSchemeColumn` и `DataType`, что-то вроде:

```
class DataType(models.Model):
  TYPES = (
        ('EMAIL', 'Email'),
        # и т.д.
    )

  name = models.CharField()
  type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TYPES) 

class DataTypeParameter(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()
  data_type = models.ForeignKey(
       DataType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="parameters")
  value = models.CharField() # сериализированное значение параметра

class DataSchemeColumn(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()  
  data_type = models.ForeignKey(DataType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Неудобство тут, что нужно вручную сериализировать значения параметров, если они могут быть разных типов, ну или использовать другие варианты, как хранить значения разных типов (например, несколько полей разных типов `string_value`, `int_value` и т.п.).

Если используется postgres или mysql, то можно эти дополнительные параметры хранить не в отдельной коллекции, а в поле самой модели `DataType` типа `JSONField`. Тогда модель `DataTypeParameter` не нужна.